# Google Closure Compiler Ant Build without concatenating the output

Tags: bash, ant, google-closure-compiler

**1)** I finally managed to get something compiled through Google Closure Compiler [using Ant to automate the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271317/creating-a-script-to-use-google-closure-for-multiple-javascript-files). The problem im facing, is that all the examples provided concatenate the output into one main file ([main example I followed](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Building-With-Ant)), say `foo.min.js`. What I need is to minify/compile ALL the `.js` files in one and/or more directories into their respective `.min.js` files, without concatenating the output, so, lets say, I have 3 `.js` files, I need 3 minified `.min.js` outputs.

Here's my (first) current `build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="foobar" basedir="." default="compile">
    <property environment="env."/>
    <property name="env.CLASSPATH" value=""/>
    <fail message="Unset $CLASSPATH / %CLASSPATH% before running Ant!">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <equals arg1="${env.CLASSPATH}" arg2=""/>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
    <taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask" classpath="${env.CLOSURE_COMPILER}/compiler.jar" />
    <target name="compile">
        <jscomp compilationLevel="simple" warning="quiet" debug="false" output="${basedir}/admin/js/foo.min.js">
            <sources dir="${basedir}/admin/js">
                <file name="home.js" />
                <file name="mailing.js" />
                <file name="table_modal_events.js" />
            </sources>
        </jscomp>
    </target>
</project>
```

**2)** Following [Ant's installation manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#classpath), I've added this

```
<property environment="env."/>
<property name="env.CLASSPATH" value=""/>
<fail message="Unset $CLASSPATH / %CLASSPATH% before running Ant!">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${env.CLASSPATH}" arg2=""/>
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

to the top of my project, and after building successfully multiple times this way, I noticed that if I remove `<property environment="env."/>` I get a `taskdef class com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]` error. May I ask why? (being `%CLOSURE_COMPILER%` an environment variable which I also added to `PATH`) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/482511/3671226) may be related to this? But I still don't understand.

**3)** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871908/compress-all-js-in-a-folder-to-new-folder-useing-google-closure-compiler) is the closest related question/answer I could find. But it makes use of a bash script, so my question is: is it possible to achieve what I want using Ant?

I would appreciate if somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You'll have to call the compiler on each file individually. Does ant support a loop?

Comment: I think so, using `ant-contrib`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need something like into your target

```
<apply executable="java" parallel="false">
                        <fileset dir="webapp/js" includes="**/*.js" 
 excludes="any to exclude" />
                        <arg line="-jar"/>
                        <arg path="PATH/closure-compiler-XXX.jar"/>
                        <arg line="--js "/>
                        <srcfile/>
                        <arg line="--warning_level=QUIET" />
                        <arg line="--js_output_file"/>
                        <mapper type="glob" from="*.js" to="build/webapp/js/*.js"/>
                        <targetfile/>
</apply>
```